# How do I calculate the total of a shopping cart?

Tags: forms

I have the following cart implemented by a custom module I wrote.

[image: screenshot]

The columns are stored in 2 associative arrays.

```
$jcartItemQty = $_POST['jcartItemQty'];
$jcartItemPrice = $_POST['jcartItemPrice'];
```

This is what those array could contain:

```
     [jcartItemQty] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
                [1] => 1
            )

        [jcartItemName] => Array
            (
                [0] => Armas Jarnefelt - LAULAJAN KOTI
                [1] => Jean Sibelius - Kullervo
            )

        [jcartItemPrice] => Array
            (
                [0] => 110
                [1] => 120
            )
```

I need to combine somehow the arrays into one that looks like `$combined = (3 => 110, 1 => 120)` in order to be able to calculate the total.
`array_merge()` is not working because will only concatenate those 2 arrays.

```
foreach ($combined as $key => $item) {
  $total += $key * $item;
}
```

I need to display the total in a form item like this:

```
foreach ($jcartItemPrice as $key => $value) { 
  $form['jcartItemPrice'][$key] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#value' => isset($value) ? $value : '',
  );
}

$form['total'][$key] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#value' => isset($value) ? $value : '',
);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the array keys of each array will always match (and that is what you're using to tie the two arrays together):

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($jcartItemPrice as $key => $price) {
  $total += $price * $jcartItemQty[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge two arrays into one.

It looks like you're trying to overengineer things. This is a simple solution:

```
$combined = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($jcartItemQty); $i++) {
  $combined[] = array($jcartItemQty[$i], $jcartItemPrice[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Florian, nice way to pair 2 matrices. I will keep in my code snippets. Clive has a nice solution to calculate without pair it so I think we both overengineered it :) - it was my idea to pair up things :))